# Filtrar e não pegar dados repetidos firestore no flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firestore

Tenho no *Firestore* os seguites dados.

```
user1 = {'horário':'manhã'}
user2 = {'horário':'manhã'}
user3 = {'horário':'tarde'}
user4 = {'horário':'manhã'}
user5 = {'horário':'tarde'}
```

Eu crio botões de forma dinâmica com o horário.

```
bt1 = manhã
bt1 = manhã
bt1 = tarde
bt1 = manhã
bt1 = tarde
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer para não pegar dados repetidos ficando.

```
bt1 = manhã
bt1 = tarde
```

Uso o código disponível na documentação do *Firestore*

```
class BookList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading...');
          default:
            return new ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return RiasedButton(
                                   child: Text('${document[horario]}')),
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você vai montar uma lista, é interessante que os registros sejam filtrados antes de montar a lista em questão, essa é uma saída:

```
class BookList extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');

        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading...');
        default:
          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) => document["horario"]).toSet().toList().map((element) {
              return RaisedButton(child: Text(element)),
            }
          ).toList();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

*Obs.: Faça os ajustes necessário, pois não realizei testes.*

Comment: Cara. não consio testar agora, assim que conseguir aviso! 
Eu cheguei a pensar em colcoar tudo em uma lista e usar um toSet() e usar essa nova lista para criar o ListView. Acha que vale a pena?

Comment: Vale lembrar que ```document``` é um ```DocumentSnapshot```. Para se obter a string deve-se acessar com ```document[horario]```.

Comment: @FernandoFoster Eu não conhecia esse `toSet()`, aparentemente é mais simples utilizar ele sim.

Comment: @Naslausky Me esqueci de referenciar o nome do objecto mesmo... Irei corrigir

Comment: Cara se você tem um lista a = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3] e print(a.toSet()) ele imprime [1,2,3].

Comment: @Naslausky Cara qual o tipo de DocmentSnapshot? É um map certo?

Comment: @FernandoFoster Modifiquei a resposta para utilizar o `toSet()`. Como eu nunca precisei disso, nem fazia ideia da existência hahaha

Comment: Perfieto cara, era exatamente isso que eu precisava, muito obrgiado!